# react-moment library import causes error: 'Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'format')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is the **react-moment library** not working in my project?

I am using the **pnpm package manager** and have installed the **react-moment** library, `pnpm install --save react-moment` together with **moment**, `pnpm install --save moment` and **moment-timezone**, `pnpm install --save moment-timezone` libraries.
However, after importing the react-moment library in my component even before using it, `import Moment from "react-moment"` I get an error on my browser console and everything disappears from the browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'format')
    at F (index.js:11:13125)
    at Object.l (index.js:11:13816)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:11:13871)
    at n (index.js:1:447)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:11:14085)
    at n (index.js:1:447)
    at index.js:1:1246
    at index.js:1:1254
    at index.js:1:81
    at node_modules/.pnpm/react-moment@1.1.3_moment@2.29.4_prop-types@15.8.1_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-moment/dist/index.js (index.js:1:310)
F @ index.js:11
l @ index.js:11
```

Note: The Error appears even before using the module *(Just at the import statement)*.

The modules are present in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.3",
    "react-router": "^6.11.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
```

[image: Error on Browser]

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm facing same issue

Comment: maybe this will help your issue. it solved mine. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7376#issuecomment-1469998894

Comment: Are you genuinely mixing npm and pnpm?

Comment: @chochaashish not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first install, install latest version , also its works with Yarn and pnpm **
npm i react-moment

npm i moment

then,
in vite.config file paste it

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    mainFields: [],
  },
})
```

then work with Moment ,
like this

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Listingitem({ listing, id, onEdit, onDelete }) {
 
  return (
    <li className="relative bg-white flex flex-col justify-between items-center shadow-md hover:shadow-xl rounded-md overflow-hidden transition-shadow duration-150 m-[10px]">
      <Link className="contents" to={`/category/${listing.type}/${id}`}>
        <img
          className="h-[170px] w-full object-cover hover:scale-105 transition-scale duration-200 ease-in"
          loading="lazy"
          src={listing.imgUrls[0]}
        />
        <Moment
          className="absolute top-2 left-2 bg-[#3377cc] text-white uppercase text-xs font-semibold rounded-md px-2 py-1 shadow-lg"
          fromNow
        >
          {listing.timestamp?.toDate()}
        </Moment>
      </Link>

    </li>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you read the question they're not using npm

Comment: They are just package manager, I think  its applicable for npm, yarn and pnpm also

Comment: I know what they are and you cannot mix and match them.  They explicitly said they were using pnpm not npm so your answer cannot possibly work

Comment: I already try with yarn and pnpm also, its successfully worked.

Comment: On a conceptual level, there's nothing wrong with your answer. It's simply that the command isn't exactly aligned with what the OP is using. If you clarify that the commands you have in your answer are for npm (and that they need to use the equivalen pnpm command), I'm sure OP will be able to figure it out

Comment: this is a good answer. Anyone using `pnpm` can port `npm` commands over